# Split a string in Python by a specific line in text

Tags: python, regex

I want to split a body of text if there is a line which contains only "----". I am using the `re.split(..)` method but it's not behaving as expected. What am I missing?

```
import re

s = """width:5
----
This is a test sentence to test the width thing"""

print re.split('^----$', s)
```

this simply prints

```
['width:5\n----\nThis is a test scentence to test the width thing']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the [`MULTILINE` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE):

```
print re.split(r'^----$', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
```

Without it `^` and `$` were applied to the whole `s` string, not to the every line in the string:

> re.MULTILINE
>
> When specified, the pattern character '^' matches at the beginning of
>   the string and at the beginning of each line (immediately following
>   each newline); and the pattern character '$' matches at the end of the
>   string and at the end of each line (immediately preceding each
>   newline).

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> 
>>> s = """width:5
... ----
... This is a test sentence to test the width thing"""
>>> 
>>> print re.split(r'^----$', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
['width:5\n', '\nThis is a test sentence to test the width thing']
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can dont use `^` and `$` because that with `^` and `$` you specify that regex engine match from first to end of string , and use [Positive look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to keep `\n`:

```
>>> print re.split('(?<=\n)----(?=\n)', s)
['width:5\n', '\nThis is a test sentence to test the width thing']
```

Comment: What if the actual string has `----` in the middle?

Comment: @thefourtheye oh , i miss `\n` , fixed !

Comment: Why do you event need `re` for this split? Normal split won't do? ;-)

Comment: I still feel that it would fail for few corner cases, like `"abcd\n----"`. So, I would be happy with the alecxe's answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye this regex just work for occasions that `----` was between 2 new line (`\n`) , i prefer the @alexe's answer its just an alternative here !any way thanks for your attention ! ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but yes, I don't want just any random `----` to match. I specifically want a `----` on a line by itself to match.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to split without using regex.

```
s.split("\n----\n")
```

Comment: What if the string ends with `----` and without a new line character?

Comment: @thefourtheye, the OP posted in the question that the line would only contain `----`

Comment: This is what I was doing earlier on and it wasn't working in a fool proof way, hence went with the direction of using the split function from the `re` package

Answer (score 0):

less code make it perfect as expected:

IN:

```
re.split('[\n-]+', s, re.MULTILINE)
```

OUT:

```
['width:5', 'This is a test sentence to test the width thing']
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
result = re.split("^----$", subject_text, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```